# How should you calculate the average daily return on an investment based on a history of gains?

Tags: calculation, interest, rate-of-return, history

I started an Acorns account several months ago to use as a glorified savings account.  I don't make contributions on purchases, but I contribute 10% of my paycheck to it every two weeks (Richest Man In Babylon, anyone?).  I'm trying to calculate the average daily return based on account value at the start of the day vs end of the day.

Background: I initially started with my account portfolio settings set to Moderately Aggressive, thinking it might yield better gains, but after a few weeks I noticed that the losses pretty much canceled out the gains.  Since then, I've started keeping track of my account value at the start of the day and at the end of the day, taking contributions into account. I've changed my portfolio risk level each month since then, lowering it each time to see if I get better returns (so far, Moderately Conservative seems to yield better returns than more aggressive allocations, FYI).  I'm trying to determine which portfolio yields the best daily and theoretical yearly return.

I have an Excel file with several months worth of opening and closing account values.  I've been subtracting the opening value from the closing value to get the daily gain or loss, and then dividing that by the account's opening value for that day to get the %change in terms of change/initial amount.

What is the standard way to calculate the average return of data like this?  I've read that simply adding all the percents together and dividing by the number of data points doesn't create a very accurate picture.  I've also read that using `[(1+return1) * (1+return2) * ...]^1/n -1` is a more accurate way to calculate the average, but when I try this, neither excel nor my calculator will give me a real answer (because of the negatives?).  How should I convert my history of gains and losses into a statistically likely daily gain or loss?

Also, once I have the average daily gain, can I use the standard `Annual Return = [(Daily Gain +1)^365]-1` to get the theoretical annual gain (not taking future contributions into account, obviously)?

Comment: Why use the average daily gain to get the annual return, instead of using, say, the total return over the period you've been contributing?

Comment: @BrenBarn Firstly, because I don't want to wait for months using a portfolio allocation that isn't working before I have a good idea of how it compares to the others.  Secondly, because one big gain or drop on a random day might throw off the results if I measure just on that day, whereas if if take daily measurements I have a more accurate picture of the average.  A big drop could still occur randomly, but with more measurements it doesn't wrongly become the rule by accident.

Comment: The problem is that what a portfolio does from day to day is not usually a meaningful indicator of whether it's "working".  What your time horizon for these investments (i.e., when do you plan to start cashing out)?

Comment: @BrenBarn Right now I'm using it to save up some extra capital to add to my business in the next few years.  It's not really a long term investment, just a way to consistently set aside money while earning better interest than a savings account.

Comment: @BrettBarn So how would you go about this?  I started tracking it daily when it did nothing for three weeks.  Once I find an allocation that works, I'll probably stop worrying about looking at it daily, but I don't see any point in letting it dither in a risk allocation that loses as much as it makes.  I'm not worried about getting large returns, but I do want to see gains that are consistently higher than losses.

Comment: As I understand it, Acorns is investing your money in particular ETFs.  I would evaluate those ETFs on their own merits, just as if you were investing in them outside of Acorns.  In particular I would consider their asset classes (e.g., are they large cap US stocks, small cap US stocks, emerging markets, or what).  It can be dangerous to get in the habit of following the short-term performance of your investments, because there is a lot of noise in there.

Comment: Yes, it's basically a miniature hedge fund.  So what time frame would you suggest for evaluating the performance of such a fund, or of the the individual ETFs or bonds it's investing in?  To me it makes sense to track as much data as you can and then look for patterns amid the noise as you accumulate a history of data points, but how do YOU normally evaluate such things?  There probably is a way to see exactly where your money is being allocated, but I don't know how to do so, at least not beyond seeing the percentage of my contribution going into bonds, large and small cap stocks, etc.

Comment: This is getting to be a different question, but the basic answer is that you don't want to pursue very high returns if your timeframe is only a few years.  If I were planning to take the money out within, say, 5 years, I would probably not invest it in stocks at all but in bonds.  It is not even so much about evaluating the performance of the funds as understanding their asset composion.  (And their fees; apparently Acorns charges $1 but it's not clear to me if that is including or in addition to fees charged by the funds.)

Comment: @BretBarn The thing I'm finding is that as I'm lowering my risk tolerance to include more bonds and fewer stocks, the overall return, is going up.  Not huge returns, mind you, it changes by about a dollar a day, but on my latest change, that increase has been consistently positive more often than negative.  It's still early, but that's why I'm trying to track it.  I've definitely gained more than I would have if that money was in my savings account, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[(1+return1) * (1+return2) * ...]^(1/n) - 1 calculates the geometric average *daily* return.  To annualize it: [(1+return1) * (1+return2) * ...]^(**250**/n) -1.

I used 250 because that is approximately the number of trading days in the year.  If your data set includes weekends/holidays, make it 365.

As an example, if you made 25% one day and lost 20% the next, your geometric average daily return is (1.25*.8)^.5 - 1 = 0.

Comment: Cool.  That seems to work.  Do you know why this works better mathematically than a simple average?

Comment: @CMB If your stock goes up 10% one day and down 10% the next day, the arithmetic average return is zero, but the _actual_ return over two days is -1% (`1.10 * 0.90 = 0.99`)

Comment: I see.  Because if it goes up 10% from $1 to $1.10, then when it goes down 10% it's 10% of the new, bigger value of $1.10 and you lose $0.11.  So then you're really down $0.01, or 1% of the original value.

Comment: @cmb notice that the order doesn't matter: 0.9*1.1 = 1.1*0.9.  If you have a -100% return, it does not matter what the sequence of returns was before the -100%, you have nothing.  A positive return and a negative return offset when log(A) + log(B) = 0.  Note the way log(X) goes to -inf as X -> 0 and that the slope of log(x) declines as X grows (negative second derivative).